# material-ui @mui/material TextField Label not affected with the RTL direction in a next js project

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm using Material-Ui v5 in my react Project !

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import rtlPlugin from "stylis-plugin-rtl";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";

const cacheRtl = createCache({
  key: "muirtl",
  stylisPlugins: [rtlPlugin],
});

const rtlTheme = createTheme({ direction: "rtl" });

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("initial value");
  return (
    <div dir="rtl">
      <CacheProvider value={cacheRtl}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={rtlTheme}>
          <CssBaseline />
          <Box m={2}>
            <TextField
              value={value}
              onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
              label={"بريد الكتروني او هاتف"}
              variant="outlined"
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            Current Direction: {"rtl"}
            <br />
          </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </CacheProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**package.json**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpV5a.png)

my textfield behaves normally when the direction is RTL:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTnle.png)

Same code in next js project with same version Material-Ui but not same result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhmKl.png)

**package.json :**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB5tt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Orion, I can't reproduce the issue. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-carlos-lzkrd) with a working example.

Do you perhaps have a custom _document.js or _app.js where you set `dir` on the `body` element?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I found my problem by checking your example on codesandbox I wrongly installed a package instead of doing "yarn add stylis stylis-plugin-rtl", I did that "yarn add stylis-plugin-rtl"